# OpenLayers 3: does not display all Features of Layer

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, vector, wfs

I'm using `openlayers` 3 and `geoserver`. I want to get and display a `wfs` layer with `openlayers`.

this is source of my layer:

```
vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url: function (extent) {
                return 'http://myUrl/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=myLayer&' +
                    'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
                    'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
                maxZoom: 19
            }))
        });
```

and style for my vector layer:

```
new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)',
                    width: 2
                }),
                geometry: function (feature) {
                    return feature.getGeometry();
                }
```

all features are type of `MultiLineString` and loaded correctly in client. But Map does not display some of features.

`wms` from above source correctly works.

my `geojson` and geometries are correct.

please help.

Comment: What is the projection of your view?

Comment: projection is EPSG:4326. i edited post: Map does not display some of features

Comment: Maybe there is a mismatch between axis order? Try WFS 1.0.0 so you don't have axis order involved.

Comment: I checked axis order and test with other programs. It's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved.

After convert shapefile to table with postgis tools, that problem occured.

I use another ways to convert shapefile to postgresql spatial table.

**Edit**:

I use arcgis. i create connection to postgresql in arcgis and then import shapefile to postgresql spatial table.

Comment: What other way? It would be a bit more helpful if you gave some more detail..

Comment: I edit my post.